# XTK : How to render compressed dicom files(.dcm) in 3D & 2D

Tags: xtk

I am able to render '.dcm file' using X.renderer3D() and X.renderer2D(). But the issue is, the image is not displayed completely.

When I manually uncompress and test, it is working fine.

We can try to uncompress and render it at run-time, but it will be an cpu intensive operation right ?

Can any one suggest the right way to achieve the rendering of compressed dicom file.

Advance Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to know what's wrong with you

Answer (score 0):

XTK doesn't support compressed DICOM format. You could hack it in though (https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/viewerjs/io/parserDCM.js#L950-L1023). The main issue is that it requires adding external libraries to XTK.

I would recommend to use AMI that natively supports compressed DICOM format.
 AMI is still a work in progress but should already allow you to build more advanced apps. Please do not hesitate to submit feedback, pull requests, report bugs, etc.

Try to upload you DICOM images there: http://fnndsc.github.io/ami/#viewers_dicom2D

[image]

AMI on Github: https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami

Comment: Hi Nicolas ... I am not able to view dicom file over "http://fnndsc.github.io/ami/#viewers_dicom2D" ... screen looks empty.

Comment: can you share the file(s)?

Comment: when you say the screen looks empty, you mean after loading the DICOM images right?

Comment: I couldn't see any attachment option here Nicolas.

Comment: I have downloaded dicom files from http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/DATA/VOLUMEMERGpickedE.zip ..... unzipped and used one of dicom file.

Comment: Yes Nicolas ... after loading ... screen looks empty with a rectangle border.

Comment: You should be able to download now.

Comment: OK, which folder in particular is not working? I tried a couple one successfully. If you are interested in AMI, just fill a bug report on Github and we can continue the discussion there. https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami/issues/new

Comment: VOLUMEMERGE\VOLUMEMERGE\VOLUMEMERGE\IRM DE LA COLONNE CERVICO-DORSO-LOMBAIRE\STIR_TSE_MT - 501\IM-0001-0001.dcm

Comment: Almost all are not working. It's loading but it is similar to rest page color ... which is black ... but i can notice borders.

Comment: can you open the console and see if an error came ip?

Comment: as a test, does the following work: http://fnndsc.github.io/ami/examples/loader_dicoms/

Comment: examples/viewers_dicom2D/index.html
three.min.js:631 THREE.WebGLRenderer 75
models.stack.js:235 do not know how to order the frames...

Comment: three.min.js:704 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog C:\fakepath(167,37-79): error X4002: indefinite logarithm

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with default flags. (ps_3_0)
 Retrying with avoid flow control
C:\fakepath(167,37-79): error X4002: indefinite logarithm

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with avoid flow control flags. (ps_3_0)
 Retrying with prefer flow control
C:\fakepath(167,37-79): error X4002: indefinite logarithm

Comment: Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with prefer flow control flags. (ps_3_0)
Failed to create D3D shaders.

Comment: WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
three.min.js:671 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: no valid shader program in use
254three.min.js:600 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid
three.min.js:600 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.

Comment: I am seeing all these errors over browser console. I am trying this over windows, Is it fine ?

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? Edge? Can you try on Chrome? Also I opened an issue so we can continue the converstation at https://github.com/FNNDSC/ami/issues/39

Comment: Starting on wards, I am trying on chrome only. It is not working. Even I tried on firefox and internet explorer too, but result remains same. My OS windows7 ... is it an issue ? ... Better we will track this bug over github.